# What is the official way to do long-running training on google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a neural net that takes about 7-15 days to train on several GPU's.
Google colab disconnects after running the script for a few hours. There are a couple "hacks" that you can do to keep the session alive but this is obviously not the official standard.

Once I have written my script in google colab, how should I go about running the script for a long period of time? I'm connected and using google's deep learning VM's.

Comment: Is the answer you gave the industry standard? It just seems a bit amateur to be running a huge ML job spanning days in google colab.

Comment: What do you mean by "industry standard"? It's from the official Google Colab documentation. I don't get your 2nd point: (free) Google Colab is a *convenience* aimed arguably at "amateurs" (or for amateur use) free of charge; for professional use (and longer computing times), there is Colab Pro (paid), as already mentioned in the answer. What more could you possibly look for from an answer?

Comment: Running ML models in (free) Colab *is* indeed "amateurish", but this was always the idea behind (free) Colab - not to use as replacement for (possibly heavy & expensive) computing infrastructure (you already mention "several GPUs") without any cost incurred...

Comment: I just want to run the job, come back in 7 days and view the result. With the answer you posted I still have to actively babysit the training. Perhaps it was unclear from the question but I'm happy to use something other than colab for the actual training. Colab is just really good for writing the code. Atm I've hooked up colab to a google deep learning VM which has several GPU's and is paid.

Comment: Forums like Reddit are more appropriate to ask for such kind or recommendations, which are explicitly off-topic here. And since you are already using paid Google VMs, I guess you can always do the job either by a script (which is different from a *notebook*) or by a Jupyter NB running at these VMs instead of Colab; doesn't sound like you need *resources* from Colab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently **no** way of running scripts for such long times (i.e. days) in the **free** version of Colab; in fact, it is clear from the [Resource Limits](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#resource-limits) section of the official FAQ that the maximum running time is 12 hours (emphasis added):

> **How long can notebooks run in Colab?**
>
> Notebooks run by connecting to virtual machines that have **maximum
> lifetimes** that can be as much as **12 hours**. Notebooks will also
> disconnect from VMs when left idle for too long. Maximum VM lifetime
> and idle timeout behavior may vary over time, or based on your usage.
> This is necessary for Colab to be able to offer computational
> resources for free. Users interested in longer VM lifetimes and more
> lenient idle timeout behaviors that don’t vary as much over time may
> be interested in [Colab Pro](https://colab.research.google.com/signup).

So, if you really need running times in the order of days, you should consider Colab Pro.